# How do I compare two tables, match table id, and retrieve value of another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle Database. I'm very new at this and don't know much.

I have two tables, let's call them table 1, and table 2.

Table 1:

```
--------------------------------------------
config id| ISO value |  and more columns
----------------------------------------------
```

Table 2:

```
------------------------------------------
config id | ISO value | and more columns
------------------------------------------
```

Here is the problem. In the front end, the config id used is from table 1. Table 1 has 100% of the config id. Table 1's ISO values are also null.  Table 2 only has 50% of the config id used in table 1, but table 2 has an ISO value for all config id available in table 2. So, meaning no ISO value is null in table 2.

There is only one config id for every ISO value and vice versa.

Is there any way that I could compare and match the two config Id from table 1 & 2, and if there is a match, then use the ISO value found in table 2? Because in table 1, the ISO value is null. This way at least 50% of the config ids would have an ISO value. How would I write a query to do this? Or how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Especially the results -- the question is unclear on what you really want to produce.

Comment: It seems you want to update a table with partial informations contained in another table. The title of your question does not really describe your problem, but rather the algorithm you think might solve it.

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want an `outer join` when obtaining detail from table1.

```
SELECT t1.config_id, t2.iso
  FROM      table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.config_id = t2.config_id
;
```

If you want to actually update table1 with the missing iso detail, you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET iso = (SELECT iso FROM table2 WHERE config_id = table1.config_id);
```

If you're obtaining data from table2, but wish to grab corresponding data from table1, just a simple `inner join` is fine.

[Working Test Case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0f9b9c5ad365fc6dd0b41f972170c1d3)

Answer (score 0):

A simple merge with just update clause is an alternative.
This one should work:

```
BEGIN 
  MERGE INTO tbl_1 t1
  USING (SELECT config_id
              , iso_value
           FROM tbl_2
          WHERE config_id IS NOT NULL) t2
     ON (t1.config_id = t2.config_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t1.iso_value = t2.iso_value;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```